# GBrowse API for Python

Tags: python, browser, genome

Is there a python interface to GBrowse, something like Bio::Graphics in perl ? Otherwise, are there any python modules available to create genome browser like views ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me google that for you:

'python genome browser view' yields, for example, [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDUQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org%2Fcontent%2F24%2F10%2F1305.full&rct=j&q=python%20genome%20browser%20view&ei=HcVWTef8O4-u8Aalk-DHBw&usg=AFQjCNEM3rxlohei0mAFsVl6EI2DhQ-UwA&sig2=RSW-D1T8mQrrwVq_Eal6Rg&cad=rja).

Comment: Indeed, the only problem being they use a commercial charting API, so it does not help much.